# UI5 Fragment (not view) extension points from standard app ignored by framework

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

[In the SAPUI5 documentation](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/topic/403c050da4ae4566b6aafec2bc590389), views and controller extensions are mentioned, in many different ways of extending it. However, **Fragment extension is not mentioned**, and I came across a standard Fiori [Manage Promotional Offers](https://fioriappslibrary.hana.ondemand.com/sap/fix/externalViewer/#/detail/Apps(%27F2053%27)/W14) App which uses many Fragments and each one has many  tags. And these EPs are being ignored by the framework.
The [app extension's page](https://help.sap.com/docs/CARAB/dfa9dfcd457e4ba7acdfb03f30877d5f/93df7861049343f5ad8e16869058f615.html?locale=en-US&version=2.0) is outdated as if you look through the SAP Notes they introduced many more EPs than what they have in this documentation.

After debugging the standard ExtensionPoint (EP) class, I noticed it doesn't matter what you configure in the Component manifest customising, because these EPs are being ignored by the framework.

My manifest.json code trying to invoke the Fragment EP (I'm sure of the path and ext name as I debugged the std:

[image: My manifest.json code trying to invoke the Fragment EP (I'm sure of the path and ext name as I debugged the std)]

A working example of a View Extension (instead of a Fragment) in Component-dbg.js (observe the _sOwnerId prop and validation call to getOwnerIdFor() ):
[image: A working example of a View Extension (instead of a Fragment)]

And the non-working extension from the Fragment:
[image: And the non-working extension from the Fragment]

Question now is, does SAP need to fix their code to ensure the Fragment has a parent/owner so it will pass the above validation line and therefore trigger my extension? **I have manually bypassed it in debug and got the extension working without a problem**.

Or, are Fragment extensions not supported at all and not supposed to be used? But then why SAP would add so many EPs to Fragments? Or am I missing something and not using the Fragment extension properly? As mentioned I could not find any documentation on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR:** if you can control *when* and *how* the fragment gets created, refer to the below linked documentation. Otherwise, create a customer incident to inform the application developers to provide a fix in their code accordingly.

---

The most important documentation regarding this issue can be found at: [**The Owner Component**](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/a7a313889e874a118c5e17803c958b24)

Whether the framework incorporates the extension implementation or not **depends on how the app creates the fragment or view that contains the extension point.**

As you highlighted in your screenshots, the internal `ManagedObject` property `_sOwnerId` refers to the ID of the "owner" `Component` instance that was known during the instantiation of the `ManagedObject`. The owner component ID (`_sOwnerId`) is, in most cases, automatically assigned by the framework.

But if the application creates a `ManagedObject` **outside** of the "framework-managed features"<sup>1</sup>, from the framework's perspective, it's a simple class instantiation without any context of `Component`s. Typically, this is the case when the `ManagedObject` creation occurs in an asynchronous callback function or when the user presses a UI element that initiates creating the `ManagedObject` on-demand. In such cases, **the application has to provide the ID of the owner component** of which the app descriptor (`manifest.appdescr`) has the extension information. This can be done, **for example:**

- by using the newer API `this.loadFragment` (available since UI5 1.93), which **automatically assigns the owner ID**, when creating a fragment in the controller code.<sup>2</sup>
- by running the `ManagedObject` creation **within** `this.getOwnerComponent().runAsOwner(function () {/* Fragment.load, XMLView.create, etc.*/}.bind(this));`.<sup>3</sup>

### Why is the issue happening in the app?

Most likely, the application you mentioned is calling the API `sap.ui.*fragment`, `Fragment.load`, `sap.ui.*view`, or `*View.create` **outside** of the "framework-managed features"<sup>1</sup> **and** directly without `this.getOwnerComponent().runAsOwner` which is why the created fragment doesn't have any `_sOwnerId` assigned.
Keep in mind that declaratively assigned `<core:Fragment fragmentName="..." type="..."/>` in the view definition cannot have any owner ID assigned either if the view itself is also created without any owner ID.

### But why is it happening now?

In the past (I believe until around UI5 1.94), it used to "work" accidentally without the above documented solution due to a bug. UI5 fixed the bug. Albeit the *owner component* is not a well-known topic, applications should've used the `runAsOwner` API or migrated to the newer controller API `loadFragment` early instead of relying on the observed behavior that accidentally worked.

Another possible reason is that the application code has changed e.g. from creating the `ManagedObject` synchronously within the controller's `onInit` handler, where the owner ID is still known to the framework, to creating it within an asynchronous callback function.

---

<sup>1</sup> See the section "What is Handled by the Framework?" in the above linked documentation.
<sup>2</sup> [API: `sap.ui.core.mvc.Controller#loadFragment`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui.core.mvc.Controller#methods/loadFragment)
<sup>3</sup> [API: `sap.ui.core.Component#runAsOwner`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui.core.Component#methods/runAsOwner)

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive response. I've opened an incident with SAP. The "used to work accidentally" makes sense why the code was done this way, the extensions were probably working as expected during a specific version and now not anymore.

Comment: @JeferAngus It has, unfortunately, become a common issue since more and more on-prem systems are starting to migrate from using UI5 1.71 or 1.84 to one of the next maintained long-term maintenance versions (1.96, 1.108, ...).

Comment: Thank you very much for your support Hoffmann. Just to update here what I did to prove your point was switching between UI5 version on the project runtime config, where versions post 1.96 doesn't work and older version 1.84 works. It took a while to convince SAP as well via Incident, but after the above test it's undeniable and they are working on a fix still.